# Action Text attachments not working on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activestorage, actiontext

We're currently using Active Storage to upload avatar images to Amazon S3 which is working great on local as well as production

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :avatar
end
```

I'm now trying to use Action Text and followed the directions on [Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_text_overview.html) which is working perfectly on localhost

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord 
  belongs_to :user
  has_rich_text :content
end
```

When I deploy to production, however, the rich text formatting works but attachments are not being uploaded to S3 which surprised me since I assumed it's using the same active storage credentials that we used for the avatar image uploads. Strangely it's populating the `active_storage_blobs` table with the filenames even though they are not being uploaded or being referenced by `active_storage_attachments`.

Could someone help?

Comment: need your production.rb & gemfile. did you go through https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html ?

Answer (score 3):

In order to configure CORS on AWS, you need to [change the settings for your production bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/enabling-cors-examples.html).

An example CORS configuration, in JSON, would look like so:

```json
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "https://www.example.com"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

Where `https://www.example.com` is the URL of your Rails app. Make sure you **do not** allow all origins (which you would do by replacing the URL with the `*` wildcard).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the default is direct uploads in Action Text (unlike Active Storage attachments) and it works after setting up CORS on S3

Comment: So did you have to set direct uploads to false somewhere or you just adjusted the CORS on S3 alone?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to turn off direct uploads so we ended up adjusting CORS on S3. It's working fine so far